# Adding translations to installation profile upon installation

Tags: users, installation, distributions

Creating an installation profile for a french site.

I have hit a brick wall trying to have the profile install fr language translations.
I have tried adding this to my profile as this comment http://drupal.org/node/1297438#comment-6308144

```
// Add french language.
locale_add_language('fr', 'French', 'Français', LANGUAGE_LTR, '', '', true, true);
drupal_set_message(t('The language %language has been add and is now the default language.', array('%language' => 'french')));
```

Code above generates a fatal error:

```
[drush] Fatal error: Call to undefined function locale_add_language() in /home/stef/jmt-www/build/www/profiles/jmt_profile/jmt_profile.profile on line 19
```

I have the fr.po file in profile/jmt_profile/translations but have no clear way of getting the fr.po loaded. Has anyone dealt with installing secondary languages without going through ui?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must include locale.inc before:

```
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/locale.inc';
locale_add_language('fr', 'French', 'Français', LANGUAGE_LTR, '', '', true, true);
```

Comment: Hey brother. Welcome to Drupal Answers, thanks for the contribution!