# Installation profile glitch

Tags: 8, installation, installation-profiles

When I construct unattended installation using for instance:

```
drush site-install my_inst_profile \
  --account-mail='helpdesk@acme.com' \
  --account-name='siteadm' \
  --account-pass='sitepass' \
  --db-su='dbadm' \
  --db-su-pw='dbpass' \
  --db-url='mysql://drupal:drupal@mysqldb/drupal' \
  --locale='pl' \
  --site-mail='site@acme.com' \
  --site-name='MY Site' \
  --yes
```

and even the simplest possible installation profile `my_inst_profile.info.yml`, `my_inst_profile.install` and `my_inst_profile.profile` taken directly from [How to write a Drupal 8 installation profile](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-distributions/how-to-write-a-drupal-8-installation-profile), the resulted installation is malfunctioning.

The symptoms are as follows:

1. Lack of the middle part of the GUI
   [image]
2. No administrator role in the resulted system
3. Stark theme used as a default one even if `info.yml` file indicates any other theme.

It is relatively easy to handle 2 and 3 using:

```
drush role-create 'administrator'
drush config-set user.role.administrator is_admin true
```

and

```
drush pm-enable seven --yes
drush config-set system.theme admin seven --yes
```

respectively.
But the first one exceeds my Drupal capabilities.

There is some discussion and an issue queued on the net (see [Adding translations to installation profile upon installation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66313/adding-translations-to-installation-profile-upon-installation)), but the proposals are no longer valid, as there is no /includes/locale.inc and even `locale_add_language()`, in Drupal 8.

Does anybody have any hints, on how to bring together ambition to use custom distribution with necessity to build localized site?

## Addendum 1

Here is `my_inst_profile.info.yml`

```
name: my_inst_profile
type: profile
description: 'Installation profile dedicated for ACME company.'
core: 8.x

distribution:
  name: ACME Installation Profile

# Required modules
dependencies:
  - node
  - history
  - block
  - block_content
  - breakpoint
  - color
  - config
  - comment
  - contextual
  - contact
  - quickedit
  - help
  - image
  - options
  - path
  - taxonomy
  - dblog
  - search
  - shortcut
  - toolbar
  - field_ui
  - file
  - rdf
  - views
  - views_ui
  - editor
  - ckeditor

themes:
#  - bartik
  - seven
#  - stark
```

Here is `my_inst_profile.install`

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Install, update and uninstall functions for the profilename install profile.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 *
 * Perform actions to set up the site for this profile.
 *
 * @see system_install()
 */
function my_inst_profile_install() {
  // First, do everything in standard profile.
  include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/core/profiles/standard/standard.install';
  standard_install();

  // Can add code in here to make nodes, terms, etc.
}
```

Here is `my_inst_profile.profile`

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Enables modules and site configuration for a standard site installation.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function my_inst_profile_form_install_configure_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form['site_information']['site_name']['#default_value'] = 'MY Site';
  $form['site_information']['site_mail']['#default_value'] = 'helpdesk@acme.com';
  $form['admin_account']['account']['name']['#default_value'] = 'siteadm';
  $form['admin_account']['account']['mail']['#default_value'] = 'helpdesk@acme.com';
  $form['regional_settings']['site_default_country']['#default_value'] = 'PL';
  $form['regional_settings']['date_default_timezone']['#default_value'] = 'Europe/Warsaw';

}

// Add any further custom code here like hook implementations.
```

As I mentioned at the beginning, this is just a starting point for further installation profile development.

Answer (score 4):

Those are not bugs and have nothing to do with locale.

The standard install profile sets up the administrator role, the theme configuration and many other things, see standard_install() and its default configuration files like the overriden system.theme.yml.

I guess you mean the local tasks with "middle part of the GUI", that is a block and also set up by Standard, like many other blocks too.

If you create a new theme, it makes sense to look at standard on how it does things and copy the parts you need from it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please, find in the article at the very first link in my question that the only thing that my installation profile does is `standard_install();` invocation. Any penny less any penny more. Is there anything more that I should do to make standard install profile do its job properly?

Comment: Hi, again. I've just done one more test to check your hint that _Those ... have nothing to do with locale_. Indeed, when I change `locale` into `en` the phenomenon still occurs. On the other hand then I remove the installation profile from my system, the phenomenon vanishes. My conclusion is, there is something wrong with this basic installation profile. But what is it?

Comment: I find that approach of calling standard_install() strange, it saves you a few lines of code but sooner or later you will want to alter what it does or not do some things, I would just copy it. The other part of what I mentioned is config files, you didn't comment on whether you have those or not. Looks to me like you don't.

Comment: Sorry for the omission. Yes, I've got them. As a prove we can take the fact, that when I remove the custom installation profile from my system, the phenomenon vanishes regardless I enter `pl` or `en` value into `locale`. The installation is done with  `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev D8Facility --stability=DEV --no-interaction`. The custom installation profile is taken from official Druapl 8 article. So, what improvement do you suggest?

Comment: When writing the question I've inferred some insights from the [discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/1297438#comment-6308144). I see, that it is 5 years old, but the context and symptoms are very similar. Moreover, it is connected to still open [issue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2345).

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to help you further without access to the install profile. I have created multiple install profiles which all work fine, I have also done installations in different languages with --locale and that also worked fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for the benevolent approach to my question. Do you mind me asking you to share any gist from your personal snippets library? (Any more advanced D8 multilingual install profile that simply works.)

Comment: I know this question is almost a year old, but I have hit the same issue. A standard, basic, and simple installation profile created by following the docs on Drupal.org for Drupal 8, does not work. 

@utom Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @JasonGlisson Sorry for the delayed response. (Winter holiday season :-)) No, there has not arrived any value adding response from the community. As the project that was a context for this question has been suspended, and I have switched to other projects I have no longer an imperative to continue the investigation. Maybe the time will come in the future.

Comment: @utom I actually figured out a way to make this happen. You have to use a make/build file for it to really work. Using a plain installation profile will not download and configure modules. So it's missing the composer.json file and will not work. However, I was able to make this work by combining a installation profile and a make/build file. In the end, we ended up folding all of this into a docker container and are just shipping that as an entire environment.